# Who remembers my htaccess password?

Tags: .htaccess

This is a question about the functionality of htaccess password remembering. When i visit a htaccess protected website and enter my password i can visit the site without entering the password again until i change my ip address. I first thought my browser would save the password but that can't be the case because the browser shouldn't care about ip changing, right? The only option left would be that the webserver saves my ip address. But then would whoever would get my ip address after me be able to access the site without entering the password, that wouldn't be save.

Do you know who remembers my htaccess password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication method is known as [Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

As you can read from the article, the Browser has to send the credentials with EVERY request, so there is no session or similar whatsoever on the server-side.

The browser will 'remember' for a while (differs from browser to browser). I suppose it's either a coincidence that you get "logged off" whenever you change your IP, or your browser detects the connection loss and clears all cached credentials.

tl;dr: the browser

Answer (score 0):

It is the browser.
But the browser is sensitive to changes.